# Dashboard style local weather panel on app front page

Tags: iphone, dashboard, weather

Basically, I'm just looking for pointers here. Ideally, I'd just supply a GPS coordinate and get a UIView of some sort back, with a nice display of current weather conditions a la Dashboard on Mac.

The only other idea I have would be to make a simple, small webpage with a plug-in script for yr.no or some other service, and have a UIWebView on part of the start screen of the app (I can code this if this is the best option.)

Any suggestions for the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a free internet weather service for local weather (vackertvader.se, likely based on yr.no?) which offered a bunch of widget sizes. I then made a super simple web page with a few lines of HTML and added CSS to remove the background-color. Finally I created a UIWebView with opaque=NO and put a semi-transparent little rounded box between the UIWebView and the background photo of the viewcontroller. Looks really nice :)